# Fixing the width of the content in css

Tags: css

When I inspect the heading class of my webpage with chrome  , I notice that the content (i.e blue part) take the whole width of the page , how can I make it the correct width

http://www.servergreek.com/

P.S I am a beginner in CSS and i hope the question is clear enough

[image]

Comment: there is nothing blue :(. But usually the answer is width:x% can you be  a little more clear?

Comment: @LucianTarna When you use inspect element in chrome it will show

Comment: @LucianTarna  i added a pic

Comment: Try removing the `padding:60px;` is that what you looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal. Since you are using a block element with class heading, by default it will take the full width of it's parent container and that's not a problem.

A better approach to write the welcome statement:

HTML

```
<div class="heading">
   <h2>WELCOME TO 
   <span class="name"><span class="red">YT </span> ENGINE</span></h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.heading {
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 1.4;
   font-family: Arial;
}

.name {
   display: block;
}

.red {
   color: red;
}
```

live result: http://jsfiddle.net/no9p361j/

Comment: I was asking this because i have to put some buttons on the left side of ytengine-form class but the margin is taking full width

Comment: @user2650277 Alright. It would be great if you can provide us with a quick visual design of how you would like it to be :)

Comment: I just want two button to be displayed inline on the left side of the form

Comment: i just added the button but as you can see they are not appearing beside the form

Answer (score 1):

It is your `<div class="top">` and its `width : 100%;` that is causing the problem. Removing that declaration, i.e

```
.top {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  /* width: 100%; remove this */
  padding: 8px;
  color: #DDD;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Or change the padding of the .heading element

```
.heading {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 60px 0px 60px 0px;  /* changing padding*/
}
```

Both will remove horizontal scrollbar without ruining any other parts of the layout.

Comment: check my post , i added a pic

Comment: @user2650277 - see my update, both solutions will work. Did you ever tried to remove `width: 100%` from `.top`?